# /dev/ttyACM0 and lsusb

Tags: linux, zigbee

Can someone explain me the connection between /dev/ttyACM0 and the output of  lsusb?

I am following [this instructions](https://www.zigbee2mqtt.io/guide/installation/02_docker.html#running-the-container).
It says "Update ttyACM0 to match your adapter location." I do not know what to do here.

```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 1058:25a3 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. Elements Desktop (WDBWLG)
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0451:16a8 Texas Instruments, Inc. CC2531 ZigBee
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
simon@simon-itx:~/Downloads/zigbee2mqtt$ usb-devices
```

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can find your chip by doing

```
ls /dev/
```

You should find something like this tty.usbmodemXXXXXXXXXXX